# proof about limits of functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that $f(x), f'(x) and f''(x)$ are all positive for each $x \in \mathbb R$. Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\infty$.

So $f''(x)$ is the second derivative of $f(x)$. I am guessing may be we should use the MVT here? But I am not sure how. Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: Hint: recall that if a $f'(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @sardoj yes, Ok so, by intuition, I would say that if $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x \in \mathbb R$ then the limit of the function would diverge to infinity. So $f''(x)$ is irrelevant here?

Comment: @Su003, $f''$ seems irrelevant to me, too. The sign of $f'$ is all you need, if I don't miss anything here.

Comment: Ok, I get it intuitively. But how can I put it in a proper proof?

Comment: I do not share with you; what about tan^-1 which is bounded and increasing. I think $f''>0$ is for something in this exercise.

Comment: @Idris So how can we use $f''(x)$ in here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if a function is concave up on an interval it sits above its tangent lines on that interval.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f''(x) > 0 \Rightarrow \int^x_0 f''(t) dt > 0 \Leftrightarrow f'(x)-f'(0) > 0 \Leftrightarrow f'(x) > f'(0)$. Now $f'(0) >0$, since $f' >0$. Thus $f(x) > f(0) + f'(0)x$ for all $x$, thus diverges, since the lower bound function $f(0) + f'(0)x$ diverges. $f(x) >0$ seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the integrals?

Comment: Well, you can just phrase the integral argument verbally. $f''(x) >0$ means that $f'(x)$ will always increase. In particular that means $f'(x) > f'(0)$ for all positive $x$ and then the same follows.

Answer (score 1):

We will use the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit to prove this. That is, we need to show that for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, if $x\ge m$ then $f(x)\ge r$.
Let $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is strictly increasing. Thus, $f(x_2)>f(x_1)$ for all $x_2>x_1$. If $r\le0$ then any choice of $m$ will do (since $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$) so we will concern ourselves with positive $r$. If $r$ is positive then we can choose a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=r$. Let $m=x_0$ and suppose that $x\ge m$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(x)>m$ so 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$
by the definition of the limit.

Comment: The step where I said to choose $x_0$ with $f(x_0)=r$ should probably be justified though. You can use the fact that $f''(x)>0$ to prove it.

Comment: So we can use the fact that $f''(x) >0$ to prove that there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=r$?

Comment: @Su003 As Idris said in a comment to your question, the function $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$ is increasing but bounded. Therefore you would not be able to choose $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=r$ for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$. Essentially, you should use the fact that $f''(x)>0$ to show that $f$ is not bounded above because my proof did not deal with that possibility.

Comment: So the fact that $f''(x)>0$ means that $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$ right? Does this show that $f$ is not bounded above?

Comment: @Su003 Yes, since $f''(x)>0$ then $f'(x)$ is strictly increasing. That statement alone is not enough to prove that $f$ is unbounded but I am sure that you can use it to explain _why_ $f$ cannot possibly be bounded above.

Comment: Does it matter if $f''(x)$ is bounded or unbounded in this case?

Comment: So basically, to show that $f$ is unbounded, we have to show that there is a real number $M$ such that $|f(x)|>M$?
I am kinda lost.

Comment: I am trying to related the fact that $f''(x) >0$ to $f$ being unbounded. 
So if $f''(x)>0$ then $f'(0)$ is strictly increasing on all $x \in \mathbb R$. But how does this means that $f$ is unbounded? :/

Comment: But if a function is strictly increasing, doesn't it mean that it doesn't converge? This would mean that it is not bounded above and therefore unbounded right?

Comment: @Su003 A picture might help. Suppose $f$ is strictly increasing and bounded above. Notice that if this is the case then $f$ is concave down. This is not possible since $f''(x)>0$ so $f$ is concave up. This shows that $f$ is not bounded above.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much! Also, could you please clarify for me how you got from 'Since $f$ is strictly increasing then $f(x)>m$' to $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$?
Thanks

Comment: @Su003 I used the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ (see the second sentence of my answer for the statement of the definition). I showed that given any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we can choose $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that if $x\ge m$ then $f(x)\ge r$. That proves that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Ok, so $f(x)>m$ would mean that $f(x) \geq r$?

Comment: @Su003 Not necessarily. The point is that if $x\ge m$ then $f(x)\ge r$ since $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this by applying the MVT to $f$ on each interval $[k,k+1]$ for $k=1,2, 3,...$?